# Change drawable color programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the color on a white marker image by code. I have read that the code below should change the color, but my marker remains white.

```
Drawable.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, Mode.MULTIPLY )
```

Did I miss something? Is there any other way to change colors on my drawables located in my res folder?

Comment: accepted answer didn't work for me..used this [answer][1], 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940825/android-change-shape-color-in-runtime

Comment: I think all the answers here change the background color, but not color of the image. Im i right? can anyone tell me please? I tried all the solutions here and also on same questions on stackoverflow, but they change only background color in may case. So i think, we can only change background color, but not the images color. I'm I right?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66479081/3503855

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Try this:

```
Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_drawable); 
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED);
```

Using `DrawableCompat` is important because it provides backwards compatibility and bug fixes on API 22 devices and earlier.

Comment: Hmm, the color remains white. Could it have to do with the hello mapview `OverlayItems` class that might be causing the problem? Its a regular drawable from my res folder, nothing special...

Comment: You might prefer PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN if you want it to work with a wider range of source colors.

Comment: PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY did not changed anything for me ( Black star with transparent background). i used the PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP for coloring the actual bitmap.

Comment: There's also a convenience method you can use: `setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)`

Comment: PorterDuffColorFilter constructor takes ARGB color format

Comment: will be interesting to mutate the drawable with #mutate() to avoid share its state with any other drawable, otherwise if you reuse the drawable could have wrong color.

Comment: The drawables are shared amongst all getDrawable from resources, hence the mutate() call is required to be able to change the tint of a drawable, without altering all the drawables associates with that resource ID, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593641/5555218

Answer (score 164):

You can try this for svg vector drawable

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(
    DrawableCompat.wrap(myImageView.getDrawable()),
    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.another_nice_color)
);
```

Comment: Best way I've seen for svg.

Comment: prefer this over the accepted answer, although both will work, but with this one I don't have to worry about what drawable to set, i just get the one already there, and it's also backward compatible, great!

Comment: Best answer when nothing worked iot work like a charm! Thanks a lot! Note: It also works for when you have a xml drawable in your imageView/AppCompatImageView

Comment: How to remove it programatically ?

Comment: @HardikJoshi Documentation says: *To clear the tint, pass `null` to `Drawable#setTintList(ColorStateList)`*

Comment: Unfortunately, this overrides the set stroke in the xml file, whereas the color filter option doesn't

Comment: Correction, it only does so when not setting a mode. When using `DrawableCompat.setTintMode(bgDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)` before applying the tint, it works the same as color filter.

Comment: Remember to use `mutate()` or else you'd change the colour of the drawable globally!

Answer (score 37):

You may need to call mutate() on the drawable or else all icons are affected.

```
Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_my_icon).mutate();
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorIcon, typedValue, true);
icon.setColorFilter(typedValue.data, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: What really make your answer incredible is  `mutate()` that really what I was searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

You can try this for `ImageView`. using `setColorFilter()`.

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorWhite));
```

Answer (score 22):

Another way to do this on Lollipop, android 5.+ is setting a tint on a bitmap drawable like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    android:tint="@color/red_tint"/>
```

This will work for you if you have a limited number of colors you want to use on your drawables. [Check out my blog post for more information](http://toastdroid.com/2014/12/06/tinting-drawables-on-lollipop/).

Comment: Nice! Btw, this seems to work fine on pre-Lollipop too. (Just tested this with `minSdkVersion 16` and Android 4.1.1 device.)

Comment: When creating a bitmap this way, it does not stretch to fit the layout as it would when using `android:background="..."`. Pretty strange!

Comment: I think that's because you are not creating a nine patch here.

Comment: Sorry this page does not exist =(

Comment: @Jonik The answers in your provided question are irrelevant. This question is asking for the way to change *Drawable*'s colour, not ImageView.

Answer (score 13):

I have wrote a generic function in which you can pass context, icon is id drawable/mipmap image icon and new color which you need for that icon.

This function returns a drawable.

```
public static Drawable changeDrawableColor(Context context,int icon, int newColor) {
    Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, icon).mutate(); 
    mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)); 
    return mDrawable;
} 

changeDrawableColor(getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_action_tune, Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 10):

You could try a ColorMatrixColorFilter, since your key color is white:

```
// Assuming "color" is your target color
float r = Color.red(color) / 255f;
float g = Color.green(color) / 255f;
float b = Color.blue(color) / 255f;

ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
        // Change red channel
        r, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        // Change green channel
        0, g, 0, 0, 0,
        // Change blue channel
        0, 0, b, 0, 0,
        // Keep alpha channel
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
});
ColorMatrixColorFilter cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
myDrawable.setColorFilter(cf);
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me. Make sure to put "ff" between 0x and color code. Like this 0xff2196F3

```
Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.ic_vector_home);
                    mDrawable.setColorFilter(new
                            PorterDuffColorFilter(0xff2196F3,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
```

Comment: Hi @Bek welcome to stackoverflow. If this worked for you, it would be very helpful to include a jsfiddle with minimal solution to show that. It will help the person who posted question to understand properly.

Answer (score 6):

Same as the accepted answer but a simpler convenience method:

```
val myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_drawable)
myDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(myDrawable, null, null, null)
```

Note, the code here is Kotlin.

Answer (score 6):

**For those who use Kotlin** a simple extension function:

```
fun Drawable.tint(context: Context,  @ColorRes color: Int) {
    DrawableCompat.setTint(this, context.resources.getColor(color, context.theme))
}
```

and then simply do

```
background.tint(context, R.color.colorPrimary)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this: For java

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#343434"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
```

for Kotlin

```
view.background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#343434"),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
```

you can use PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP, if your background has rounded corners etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try `Mode.LIGHTEN` or `Mode.DARKEN`. The Android Javadocs are horrible at explaining what the PorterDuff Modes do. You can take a look at them here: [PorterDuff | Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html)

I suggest looking around at Compositing on Mozilla's site [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing) (They don't have all the modes that android does but they have a lot of them)

Answer (score 3):

You can change your drawable color in this way:

```
background = view.findViewById(R.id.background)

val uDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.context, R.drawable.background)
uDrawable?.let {
      val wDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(it)
      DrawableCompat.setTint(wDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(view.context, 
                                                      color /*specify your int color code*/))
      background.background = wDrawable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax**

```
"your image name".setColorFilter("your context".getResources().getColor("color name"));
```

**Example**

```
myImage.setColorFilter(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.deep_blue_new));
```

Answer (score 2):

SDK >= 21 one line
myIconImageView.getDrawable().setTint(getResources().getColor(myColor))

Comment: Pretty nice, I recommend to use 
`Drawable newDrawable = myDrawable.mutate().setTint(getResources().getColor(myColor))`
to avoid changing it globally

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin Version**

```
val unwrappedDrawable =
            AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable)
        val wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable!!)
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

```
public static Drawable changeDrawableColor(int drawableRes, int colorRes, Context context) {
    //Convert drawable res to bitmap
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableRes);
    final Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
            bitmap.getWidth() - 1, bitmap.getHeight() - 1);
    final Paint p = new Paint();
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, p);

    //Create new drawable based on bitmap
    final Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), resultBitmap);
    drawable.setColorFilter(new
            PorterDuffColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(colorRes), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
    return drawable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Method like this :

```
//CHANGE ICON COLOR
private void changeIconColor(Context context ,int drawable){
    Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawable);
    assert unwrappedDrawable != null;
    Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
}
```

and use it like it :

```
    changeIconColor(this,R.drawable.ic_home);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Way to do it :

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(r, g b));
```

or

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(a, r, g, b));
```

a, r, g, b : Color argb values.

Comment: This will only work if the OP would have be using imageViews instead of drawables.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short :

**May 2023**
Kotlin (all APIs):

```
 DrawableCompat.wrap
     (AppCompatResources.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.myDrawable)!!)
    .mutate()
    .also { DrawableCompat.setTint(it,0xFFff0000.toInt()) }
```

⚠ don't forget the `mutate`, a mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other! This is especially useful when you need to modify properties of *drawables loaded from resources*. By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification. Calling this method on a mutable Drawable will have no effect.

Old - Java :

```
public Drawable getColoredDrawable(@DrawableRes int resid,int color){
    Drawable drawable= ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resid).mutate();
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    return drawable;
}
```