# Android backgroud image slow the app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I m using DrawerLayout for left slide menu. My app is getting slow when I use image for background. On the other hand it smooth when I m using color for background.

**my code is**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here my background image is  `@drawable/app_bg` I don't know how to overcome this and achieve smooth slide move.

My background image .

[image]

Comment: you want a background image for your `FrameLayout` or your sliding menu?

Comment: i want background image for FrameLayout.even I set background image for FrameLayout it also slow

Comment: Alright, have a look at my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Background Image Size (in Pixel) which Support All Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024272/android-background-image-size-in-pixel-which-support-all-devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have diferente sizes for deferent displays. Multi screen support please take a look at this [Android: Background Image Size (in Pixel) which Support All Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024272/android-background-image-size-in-pixel-which-support-all-devices)

Answer (score 1):

If your image is causing your app to slow down, what you can try is to use a `<gradient>` as a background. Create a gradient in your drawables folder and set it as a background for your `FrameLayout`

Alternatively,

You can add an `ImageView` to your `FrameLayout` as the bottom-most view and add the image to it. Set the width and height to `match_parent` and the crop type to center. Hopefully, that will do the trick.

Also,

I hope you have the same image for different densities. Same name but different sizes and in appropriate drawable folders.