# identify the correct android dpi folder for a new picture

Tags: android, screen, dpi

Assuming that I have shot a picture with 400*800 pixels. I know how to convert this picture from one density into another density. But which one is the first (when i create a new picture)?

Comment: What size will you be showing the image in your application?

Comment: 400*800 is "close to" 480*800 (WVGA), which is the `typical` **hdpi** resolution for phones (some use 480*854 / FWVGA). So, I'd say this is suitable for the `drawable-hdpi` folder.

Comment: My image will use full width and 2/3 full height on vertical orientation. Is there a pixel-range for mdpi?

Comment: In **phones**, the typical mdpi resolution was 240*320.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good screen size overview: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024272/android-background-image-size-in-pixel-which-support-all-devices)

This pixel-calculator is useful too: [Pixel Calculator](http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/)