# Another topic about background image sizes

Tags: android, image, responsive-design, size

Let's imagine I want a picture of my dog as a background picture of a layout, and I want my application to be running on every smartphones.

I've read a lot of articles about this, and I just want to be certain that my dog will still look like a normal dog even if I use a tablet, a Nexus 5, or a moto G.

This subject is really similar to my problem:
[Android: Background Image Size (in Pixel) which Support All Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024272/android-background-image-size-in-pixel-which-support-all-devices)

According to the comments, it's not possible to have one image per resolution, because we have too many resolutions for android.

I just want an image of my dog as a portrait background.

Is it possible to do it? What is the easiest way to do it? What if my layout height is not exactly equal to the device screen height, but the device height minus another layout (fixed size) ?

Comment: Use 9 Pach Image, hope it will solves your problem. Here is the link for it http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html  or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gangulian, but if I'm right 9patch is for really easy images, such as a button. I think my dog is too complex to be set as a 9patch image. Am I right?