# Setting background image in android application

Tags: android, xml, background

For few last days I'm trying to set background image in my android application. First I added my image to res/drawable-hdpi and set it as a background in .xml code of my activity by writing

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bground"
    tools:context="patrycja.MainActivity" >
```

It didn't work so I tried also to put this image into another drawable folder in res - without success. Then I even changed the extension of my file from .jpg to .png - nothing.
So I got into res/values/styles.xml and added this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bground</item>
 </style>
```

Everytime my application compiles but when I try to start it I can't even go to my first activity because it stops. LogCat shows me RuntimeException, InvocationTargetException and OutOfMemoryError. Problem must be here because my app works good with setting colour as a background.
Has anybody got an idea how to fix it?

Comment: whats the size and format of the image>

Comment: The size of an image is too high I guess.

Comment: It's 2395x3491 pixels. Is it too big?

Comment: @lawstud Yes of course. On which type of device you are targeting? Phone or tablet? What is the actual size of that image?

Comment: My target is Nexus One. I've changed size into 300x437 and it finally worked! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @lawstud Your welcome. Try to put image sizes not too much larger. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228830/1820644) answer for screen resolutions. You can use this as a background image and put it in different folders with different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Use a .JPEG background.
2. Keep it in res/drawable-nodpi directory.

I think this will work as I have faced a similar crash earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately it crashed again.

Comment: I think the resolution of the image is too high. I did this with 1280x720 image. No problem faced till now. Can you try with an image of lower resolution?

Comment: I resized it to 300x437 px and now it works. Thanks a lot :)