# How to fit image with match_parent without blur

Tags: android, imageview

I have a drawable that i want to put in my intro Screen using Image View:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/intro_applogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_intro_logo"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

As you can see im using layout_width and layout_height as match_parent, until that its all ok, the problem is the image appears with blur (see screenshot), how can i do this without getting my image with blur?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what is the size of your image, I think you image has low resolution. Use a more resolution image, inshort use a bigger image

Comment: It is showing blur cause your image is stretched. Try with proper Image resolution. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024272/android-background-image-size-in-pixel-which-support-all-devices

Comment: @RanjanDas i think is not the resolution, cause me graphic has a high resolution, 600 pixels per inch, and the original image is big enough, but i inserted the graphic using image asset and Android Studio created drawables for all screen sizes, maybe that caused the issue.

Comment: Try this image, http://www.hdiphonewallpapers.us/phone-wallpapers/freewallpaper/129604314MG40-29254.jpg

Comment: If not then post your code and xml

Comment: @RanjanDas, it works, was the resolution of the image, I learned a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create separate drawables for different densities

Read https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For example you can choose drawable which will fit 200x200dp. So, you should create files

> res/drawable-mdpi/ic_intro_logo.png (200x200)
>
> res/drawable-xxdpi/ic_intro_logo.png (600x600px)
>
> res/drawable-xxxdpi/ic_intro_logo.png (800x800px)

Actually, you do not need other drawable folders https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5xP4tFQlkA

And finally, use minmap folder only for launcher icons [mipmap vs drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)

Comment: Thanks @DeniErdyneev, i inserted the image using image asset in Android Studio, the IDE automatically generated drawables for all screen densities, is that right?

Comment: @BrunoEstevao Yes, Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, now is ok, i created a new image tha as a more high resolution and i created myself images and resolution for all screen sizes, i didint use create image asset, i inserted the graphics through the android folders.

Comment: @BrunoEstevao good, I will appreciate you, if you vote up my answer and mark it as correct