# Android custom background xml send attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

as you can see, all it is, is a shape with rounded corners. I use it for background in activity layouts as follows:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
```

The shape in the file is currently set to white. In different layouts I need different colors. Do I need to create a different shape xml file for each color? I need a way to just specify in the layout what color to send to the background, and that way I can use the same xml for any color I want.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376516/change-drawable-color-programmatically

Comment: I am looking for a way to set it via the xml. Something like background="red" src="drawable.."

Comment: In that case, I do not believe this to be possible and you will need multiple shapes. Though I could be wrong, in which case I would like to know how to do this too :)

Comment: My question can also be translated to "Is there a way to *bind* custom attributes to xml?" May something like wpf allows

Comment: Is it possible that I can use attrs.xml for that? Or is that only for custom components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Do I need to create a different shape xml file for each color?
```

- Yes,If you want to apply different color for different layout files from the **layout's xml file** itself
- No,If you apply different color for different layout files from its **java (Activity) file**.

**Solution for option 2:**

//shape drawable (rounded_corners.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

//layout file

```
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/mButton"
            ...
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            />
```

//java (Activity) file

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton); 
ShapeDrawable rounded_corners = (ShapeDrawable )mButton.getBackground();
rounded_corners.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```

I hope it will be helpful !!