# Mapbox for Android: Changing color of a marker's icon

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox in my Android app and have custom (black) icons for my markers. Is it possible to change a marker's icon color to something else if it's black?

I can also use a default icon if this is possible with default icons.

Answer (score 12):

Mapbox Android SDK uses a PNG file for the marker icon. You can use any PNG file as an icon, in other words the marker can be just about any color you want. [Heres an example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/custom-marker-icon/) with a marker using a custom icon. Heres the code doing most the work:

```
            // Create an Icon object for the marker to use
            IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
            Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.purple_marker);
            Icon icon = iconFactory.fromDrawable(iconDrawable);

            // Add the custom icon marker to the map
            mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(-33.8500000, 18.4158234))
                    .title("Cape Town Harbour")
                    .snippet("One of the busiest ports in South Africa")
                    .icon(icon));
```

Here are some markers I made using the same style as the default icon:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Place these in your projects `drawable-xxhdpi` folder. These are pulled from the [Mapbox Android Demo app](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo) you can get from the [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo)

Comment: Thanks! I don't think this lets me change the color programmatically, though. I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376516/change-drawable-color-programmatically

Comment: In my situation I am dealing with bitmaps as the source of the pin gfx is not coming internally within the app but coming from server. I have to download this  marker icon from the server. Every time I setIcon multiple times for some occasion, the marker removes itself from the map. I wonder why? I guess its going OOM.

Comment: Unfortunately this will no longer work since fromDrawable is no longer supported. fromResource with a png (R.drawable.<name>) will work though.

Answer (score 3):

I use this

```
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat,lng))
            .icon(IconFactory.getInstance(this).fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change color of an icon programmatically

```
Drawable iconDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.your_marker, null);
iconDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(iconDrawable);
//Changing color to white
DrawableCompat.setTint(iconDrawable, Color.WHITE);
//Use this icon in addMarker(new MarkerOptions()...
Icon icon = iconFactory.fromDrawable(iconDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

For SDK versions 5+ the other solutions don't work anymore because the method `fromDrawable()` is not available anymore.

Use this approach to create a tinted icon from a drawable resource:

```
public static Icon drawableToIcon(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int id, @ColorInt int colorRes) {
    Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), id, context.getTheme());
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
    vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(vectorDrawable, colorRes);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return IconFactory.getInstance(context).fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

The code snippet is taken from this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7897), which also explains why `fromDrawable()` is not available anymore.