# How to change background color of drawable shape in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-adapter, android-drawable

I have a button in my custom listview item for which I am using following drawable xml file:

rounded_corner.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="100dp">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <solid android:color="#002832" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

I have used "#002832" color for that drawable. Now, I want to change the color of drawable file programmatically. How can i do this?

**PLEASE STOP MARKING AS DUPLICATE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING THE QUESTION.**

1. I have checked @Ganesh Pokele SO link anf which totally different.
2. I have checked @bizzard provided link but could not solve my issue.

Comment: check this example of Listview selecter [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2830994/3522570)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change drawable color programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376516/change-drawable-color-programmatically)

Comment: ((GradientDrawable)someView.getBackground()).setColor(someColor);

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I described what you want in detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197343/6286328), you might want to check it out, if I understood well your question.

Basically, what you should do is create **another** drawable with a different color and set it programmatically through yourView.setBackground(Drawable drawable):

**another_round_corner.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="100dp">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#002832" />

    <solid android:color="#002832" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Then set the background as this drawable whenever you want.

**EDIT**

As OP does not want to use another drawable, a solution would be to use a color filter like this:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.rgb(40, 50, 60), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

You will obtain the desired effect. `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` will apply the color you want on the background, on top of another color, without mixing them. You have to pass the color in the first argument (the color will come from the server). If it's in hex, just convert it to RGB, in example, or do whatever transformation you need.

You can always change the drawable color programmatically like that, let me know if it works for you.

Let me know if it helps you, and upvote/select as correct answer if it did, cheers.

Comment: The color of drawable could be any so creating a new drawable won't help. Let me know if u have any other idea.

Comment: But what is the deal about creating another drawable?

Comment: The color will come from server and it could be anything so what's the point to create another drawable. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It does make sense. Alright, check my updated answer and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to know

Comment: It resolved my issue in the way which is exactly i want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. If you want to change drawable color dynamical using programatically so use this code.

This is my xml **rectangle_border**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/gray"
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
      <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

2. Here i am change dynamical background color

```java
 Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.rectangle_border);
            Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.parseColor(textcolor));
            //Here set the background in view
            holder.textrectangle_bgLL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_border);
```