# Change android button drawable icon color programmatically

Tags: android

I want to change my icon color from my button programmatically...

On my xml, i have:

```
            android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_car_black_24dp"
```

To set the icon and set the icon color... But i want to change the icon color from my java side...

Can someone help me?

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_search_vehicle_car"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/eight_density_pixel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_blue_border"
            android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_car_black_24dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/eight_density_pixel"
            android:text="Carros"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 20):

First of all, do not use `AppCompatButton` directly unless you write a custom view and you want to extend it. The normal `Button` will be "resolved" by the system as `AppCompatButton` so you don't need the latter.

As for your original question, there are multiple ways to tint a drawable. You can use [`DrawableCompact`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) to do it in a "tinting" fashion while you can use a normal [`ColorFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) to do this in a "filtering" fashion.

#### Tinting with `DrawableCompat`

Use `DrawableCompat` to [wrap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#wrap(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) the drawable so it can be [tinted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#setTint(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int)) on older platforms.

```
Button yourButton = findViewById(R.id.bt_search_vehicle_car);

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_car_black_24dp);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

yourButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null);
```

#### Using `ColorFilter`

Use the [`Drawable.setColorFilter(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)) method to set an overlaying color filter for your drawable.

```
Button yourButton = findViewById(R.id.bt_search_vehicle_car);

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_car_black_24dp).mutate();
drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

yourButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null);
```

Comment: Well, the `setCompoundDrawables` only works when we configure rectangle bound.

The workaround is using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBound` if we don't want to specify the bound explicitly.

Answer (score 12):

Use setCompoundDrawableTintList property to change color
i use it as following

```
btn_recent.setCompoundDrawableTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ff9708")));
```

Comment: setCompoundDrawableTintList requires  "min Api  = 23"

Answer (score 5):

I use vector drawable as drawableLeft for the Button and changed the button drawable colour programmatically using **Kotlin** like this.

```
button_id.compoundDrawableTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue))
```

Comment: requires Android M (23)

Answer (score 3):

```
public void setTextViewDrawableTintColor(TextView textView, int color) {
    for (Drawable drawable : textView.getCompoundDrawables()) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(), color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that you need to change the `android:drawableTint` property.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376516/change-drawable-color-programmatically), you need to create a new drawable with a different tint, then change the drawable resource for your button.

Create a `Drawable` from your icon:

```
Drawable mDrawable=getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_car_black_24dp);
```

Then change its tint:

```
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

One you've done this, set your new `Drawable`:

```
yourButton.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
```

I suggest you to skim through the comments of the linked question and [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) to discover different `PorterDuff` modes.

Comment: I need to set a diferent image? I can't change only the color of the image?

Comment: You need a different drawable to do this. I assume you need to change the `ic_car_black_24dp` icon, right?

Comment: No, i just need to change the color of the ic_car_black_24dp... When i use drawableTint, i can change the color... but in xml... I didn't find any attribute to change this on java side

Comment: Oh alright, my bad. Let me check some stuff and I will edit my answer

Comment: Working on it... when i finish the implementation, i'll feedback you, just wait some minutes please

Comment: i found this: setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds to change my drawable image... Now i need only to change the image... This method not working

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check my approach to change button colour dynamically through data binding adapter with kotlin based on your question. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55205149/3763032)

I've also mentioned and reference the original answer also the article for an alternative solution or get a better understanding of the workaround