# How to have multiple theme in my android app?

Tags: android, styles, themes

This is the home screen of my app. I have used `Drawable` and `Color` resources in the design. Now I want to have multiple color sets (for the parts with cyan color) so user can change them at run time. I searched a lot, but they don't fit my case.

Note that I want just the cyan colored parts to change. I know I can change all the `TextView` styles using `style` attribute, but I just need certain views get certain drawables or colors as background.

I found a solution [here](https://medium.com/@vinitagrawal91/android-colors-and-multiple-themes-fdfca3f75a15) but I cannot use it because it needs the min sdk higher than 21 while mine is 16.

[Home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR7KF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set theme like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.your_theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not my case

Answer (score 0):

Define your style in `values/styles.xml` like so:

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColorCyan</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColorCyan</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColorCyan</item>
</style>
```

And then call `setTheme(R.style.MyTheme)` before `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` method. `setTheme` introduced in `API LEVEL 1`.

Comment: Suppose I have a drawable which uses the colorPrimary. How do I reference to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376516/change-drawable-color-programmatically/47299270  @Saj