# Change ImageButton states background color on runtime

Tags: android, background, runtime, imagebutton

I need to change colors from a selector whatever on runtime and i need to apply it to 4 different buttons.

Here is the ImageButton code:

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/buttonAgenda"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"           
   android:background="@drawable/drawable_button_states_corners"
   android:src="@drawable/boton_agenda_1"/>
```

The drawable_button_states_corners:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <solid android:color="@color/galicia2"/>    
        <corners 
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
    </shape>         
</item>
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <solid android:color="@color/galicia"/>    
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
    </shape>   
</item>
</selector>
```

I need to change both solid colors and i don't know how to acces them. I've already tried accesing background's imagebuttons but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create another state_corners with desired colors and change drawables as you wish

Comment: how do i change drawables? I'm setting background wich is where i set the drawable but it won't change, in fact, it's loosing the default drawable

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get the states of StateListDrawable so its not possible to modify it (unless you created SLD using default ctor and addState() method), but you can always create a new SLD and addState()s

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know to achieve what you want you have to create shape drawable at runtime and then you can creat state list to set as background . You can create shape drawable at runtime with this code

```
ShapeDrawable footerBackground = new ShapeDrawable();

// The corners are ordered top-left, top-right, bottom-right,
// bottom-left. For each corner, the array contains 2 values, [X_radius,
// Y_radius]
float[] radii = new float[8];
radii[0] = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.footer_corners);
radii[1] = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.footer_corners);

radii[2] = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.footer_corners);
radii[3] = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.footer_corners);

footerBackground.setShape(new RoundRectShape(radii, null, null));

int color = ((Application) activity.getApplication()).getColor();

footerBackground.getPaint().setColor(color);

views.setBackgroundDrawable(footerBackground);
```

This part is taken from the accepted answer on this so post [Android: Change Shape Color in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940825/android-change-shape-color-in-runtime)

Refer to docs about creating color state list at runtime http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html