# Android - Change drawable color in runtime

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I''m using a **drawable** for the cells in my **table layout** in my Android application. I want to change the cell colors on click event. Is it possible to change the color of the drawable in run time. my drawable is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#483D8B"/>
</shape>
```

And I want to change the white color "#FFFFFF" with the click event. Can Java edit the color in the XML drawable file? I just edited the background color and it dispersers the borders of the drawable.

```
String StatusColor=GetColor(Retailer_x.getStatus());
Stts.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(StatusColor));
```

Comment: where is your runtime code - show us what you have tried.

Comment: Similar question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940825/android-change-shape-color-in-runtime

Comment: @ user2310289 I just edited background color of the cell. In this case a text view was in the cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
                        sd1.getPaint().setColor(CommonUtilities.color);
                        sd1.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
                        sd1.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(CommonUtilities.stroke);
                        sd1.setPadding(15, 10, 15, 10);

                        sd1.getPaint().setPathEffect(
                                new CornerPathEffect(CommonUtilities.corner));
                        ln_back.setBackgroundDrawable(sd1);
```

Comment: this is fine. But got some problem. I edited the CommonUtilities.stroke as "5". and sets the releven color for CommonUtilities.color. But it gives only the borders. Other part is empty. can you help me to fix this. Thank you!!!

Comment: I fix it. I used a LinearLayout and add the textView into it. Set the background color for LinearLayout and set the drawable to textView. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: sd1.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE); replace with sd1.getPaint().setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

Answer (score 1):

Use `selector` of the Table Cell background to change state of the table cell when user click it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_drawable" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_drawable"/>
    <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: no no. I mean another thing. There are a number of states that the cell can represent and on click I can change the state. So I need to change the color on that state. any idea... Thank you!!