# How to make a drawable Shape programmatically (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-drawable

i'm making a custom TextView (Java class) and i'm having trouble "to translate" the line (on "original TextView" xml)

```
android:background="@drawable/myDrawableShape"
```

to a java void to change the color of the "myDrawableShape"

myDrawableShape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="#ffafafaf" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />
```

I'll get the color to set from a String, the void to change the color programmatically could be (for example)

```
void colorSet(String color)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your questions.  Are you asking how to set a TextView's background programmatically to a drawable?  If so, this would be the code (ContextCompat is part of the v4 support library): textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MyActivity.this, R.drawable.myDrawableShape));

Comment: Explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940825/android-change-shape-color-in-runtime) post. See the first answer.

Comment: Sorry for my english!!

No, i want to change the "android:color="#ffafafaf" " on the XML drawable from the code.

So like it now works, i need a xml for each color. What i want is to change the color from the code when creating the textview from a customTextview class, something like createText(String color)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can then create your Shape Drawable in Java itself using below code.

```
public Drawable getRoundRect() {
    RoundRectShape rectShape = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{
            10, 10, 10, 10,
            10, 10, 10, 10
    }, null, null);

    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(rectShape);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    return shapeDrawable;
}
```

Comment: Worked!  boh Hut!

Answer (score 1):

Change Color:

```
  TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_time);

    Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);

    if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
        // If 'ShapeDrawable'
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) background;
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
    } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        // If'GradientDrawable'
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
        gradientDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));
    } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        // If ColorDrawable
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
        colorDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
    tv.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: Returns error "because loading a GradientDrawable on a Drawable" :/

Comment: the Muthukrishnan Rajendran code worked perfectly, but thanks!