# Setting the color of a shape programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to set the color of my shape programmatically, inside my drawable I created a rounded shape (rounded_button.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00b248" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

And now I want to change it color in my activity.

```
public void setShapeColor() {
    Drawable shapeDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.rounded_button, null);
    shapeDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

But it does not work and holds still the same color.

Comment: this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940825/android-change-shape-color-in-runtime

Comment: Did you try other modes like PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN?

Comment: @easy_breezy I failed with that aswell

Answer (score 0):

This how you can change color defined drawable in xml

```
LayerDrawable shapeRectangle = (LayerDrawable) getDrawable(context, R.drawable.custom_layer);
GradientDrawable gradient = (GradientDrawable) shapeRectangle.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape_rectangle);
gradient.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: What is titleTextView in my case?

Comment: What is the Layer id? the drawable name is rounded_button but it has no id

Comment: so define an ID for each <item android:id="add_id_here" ... /> or other item you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tint to made tint of drawable.

example:

```
fun getTintDrawable(context:Context, resId: Int, tint: Int): Drawable? {
    val normalDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId)
    var wrapDrawable = if (normalDrawable == null) null else DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable)

    if (wrapDrawable != null) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, tint)
    }

    return wrapDrawable
}
```

Sorry that i use kotlin, but rewrite to java could not take so much time.
Hope it helps.

BR

Comment: Can you rewrite to java, not familiar in kotlin at all

Comment: @Jonnotdoexx check my answer, I have posted it in java for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Nullable
public Drawable getTintDrawable(Context context, int resId, int tint) {
    Drawable normalDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
    Drawable wrapDrawable = (normalDrawable == null) ? null : DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable);

    if (wrapDrawable != null) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, tint);
    }

    return wrapDrawable;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if helps. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

As requested by @Jonnotdoexx

Same code in Java:

Please note that this function will return null if first `if` clause fail to execute.

```
Drawable getTintDrawable(Context context, int resId, int tint) {
    Drawable normalDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
    Drawable wrapDrawable;
    if (normalDrawable != null) 
        wrapDrawble = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable);
    if (wrapDrawable != null) 
       DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, tint);
    return wrapDrawable;
}
```